# Not working Transitions effect where click in Navigato thumbnail (Jssor Slider)

Tags: transition, effect, jssor

This config jssor slider

```
var options = {
    $AutoPlay: true,
    $FillMode: 4,
    $AutoPlayInterval: 5000,
    $PauseOnHover: true,
    $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,
    $SlideWidth: 933,
    $SlideHeight: 304,
    $DragOrientation: 0,
    $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
        $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,
        $ChanceToShow: 2,
    },
    $NavigatorOptions: {
        $Class: $JssorNavigator$,
        $ChanceToShow: 2,
        $ActionMode: 2,
        $AutoCenter: 0
    },
    $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
        $DisableDrag: false,
        $ActionMode: 0
    },
    $SlideshowOptions: {
        $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,
        $Transitions: [{$Duration:1200,$Opacity:2}]
    },
};
var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('slider2', options);
```

When you click on the thumbnails for some reason does not work transition effect. When triggered click usual effect of the transition (from right to left). 
How to do so would in click thumbnail breakdowns effects specified in $SlideshowOptions -> $Transitions

Answer (score 0):

Sliding carousel (left <--> right) is the main feature of jssor slider.

When you touch drag by finger or mouse, or click navigation control, or calling by api, it will trigger the carousel scrolling.

Slideshow transitions play automatically only.

Comment: In my opinion this is probably not the main feature of the slider and its deficiency. Since it is not logical. 
We asked for a certain height slider effect that should be considered when using the navigation controls. 

Is it possible in this slider to disable this "feature", or not?

Comment: This is main feature different from all other sliders, and it is getting popular.

Comment: We should be able to disable carousel feature when slideshow options are specified, giving slideshow more flexibility.

Comment: Yes, we need one more option. I will consider this feature for later update.

Comment: I hope this new option is included. Some users (like me) may prefer subtle transitioning direct to the selected image without scrolling through other images in between. But great work and perhaps the best slider available. Thanks a lot!